# Force Checkbox to be Checked

Tags: c#, checkbox

I use this code but it's not working:

```
private void checkcheck()
{
    if (checkBox1.Text == "ON")
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
        checkBox1.ForeColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
    }
    else
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
        checkBox1.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
    }
}
```

I call this method from the form load event.

```
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = '" + label2.Text  + "' ", cn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = reader[2].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = reader[3].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = reader[4].ToString();
                checkBox1.Text = reader[5].ToString();
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
        checkcheck();
    }
```

thats it, the form load, then the checkbox change according to the data, then it sould change,
when i run it it pefectly get the data, and change check box to On/Off but no colore or check

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if it goes inside the `if (checkBox1.Text == "ON")`

Comment: are you sure your `checkBox1.Text` is "ON"?

Comment: You might need to read on http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: I'd normally do it the other way, `if (checkBox1.Checked) { checkBox1.Text = "ON"; }` Or set `.Checked` at the same time as `.Text`.

Comment: yes i t read from the database ... wait i'll add the code that read from the data

Comment: how you call `checkcheck` method ? can you post the code?

Comment: like that checkcheck();

Comment: Have you tried checkBox1.Text.Equals("ON")?

Comment: monso: nothing changed too

Answer (score 1):

since your first condition is always true the code is not executing else part.

Comment: You can't assume the first condition is always true

Comment: can you say accualy what do you want to do in here? Bcz i create a form and run this code it's working :), When i change the text manually program executes the else part.

Comment: i'll try to do thing like if = "on" do check AND if = "Off" do nocheck

Comment: How many other checkboxes do you have other than this one(checkbox1)? And are you tried this code with commenting other coding before this function call.

Comment: i need to first : get ON or OFF according to the data in the table, i already put some value like ON and OFF (i know it's a case sinstive) Second: i retrive the selected item in a checkbox.text then  to ask if it on or off and it behave on it's on or off

Comment: well, i did it in a new form and it workes, but not with this form

Comment: I think this is a problem of the data retrieve part.can you change the text of the checkbox manually and run bcz this code is work for me.

Comment: Can any one Email me to send the project and see what's wrong